# When showing a View it overlap the Items in recyclerview?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i want to show dataList from server in recyclerview and when I scroll to end of recyclerView want to show a progressbar at bottom and and also i have added a AdsView in between recyclerview but it overlaps items of recyclerView on specified index.

code:-

```
 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (contacts.get(position) == null)
        return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
    else if (position % 5 == 0)
        return AD_VIEW;
    else {
        return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;
    if (viewType == AD_VIEW) {
        View adView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add, parent, false);
        return new AdView(adView);
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view_row, parent, false);
        return new UserViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false);
        return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof AdView) {
        AdView adView = (AdView) holder;
        adView.textView.setText("Ads");
    } else if (holder instanceof UserViewHolder) {
        Contact contact = contacts.get(position);
        UserViewHolder userViewHolder = (UserViewHolder) holder;
        userViewHolder.phone.setText(contact.getEmail());
        userViewHolder.email.setText(contact.getPhone());
    } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
        LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
        loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contacts == null ? 0 : contacts.size();
}
```

xml main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

xml of itemView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_email"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

xml of loadingview:-

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: Please post the xml you have used for the purpose (Progressbar, recyclerview)

Comment: Why there need of xml

Comment: My problem is only that and extra view named as "AD_VIEW" when added it overlaps item of recyclerview at specified index ....

Comment: Please add your `add` layout xml

Comment: @Raghav any solution you got?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is needed in order to let us understand how the elements are ordered and depending on each other. 
However, until you post it, you can put your recyclerView in a RelativeLayout and set it to be below (or above) the view it overlap. 
But note that both views(the recycler and the overlapped vjew or the layout of the recycler and the overlapped view) should be under the same RelativeLayout so that they can have a position dependancy.